# How to install World of goo.deb

Tags: software-installation

I purchased the full version of World of Goo and downloaded the .deb file. When I try to launch the game from the applications menu, nothing happens. When it installed in terminal, it installed something, but didn't seem to install everything. Here's the install code from the terminal:

```
 sudo dpkg --install WorldOfGooSetup.1.41.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package worldofgoo.
(Reading database ... 173872 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking worldofgoo (from WorldOfGooSetup.1.41.deb) ...
Setting up worldofgoo (1.41) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run the game in a terminal and post the result.

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned by the author for 6 years.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command from command line:

```
$ WorldOfGoo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with gdebi, it should install all dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi gdebi-core
sudo gdebi WorldOfGooSetup.1.41.deb
```